# Select the value of max id from same date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some data,
now what i want to do is select the value of the row that has the current date and max id.

```
CREATE TABLE `pa` (
  `pd` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `ad` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `rd` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_a_d` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `l_l_d` datetime NOT NULL,
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now what I want is to select the value of the max(pd)  for the same ad when the p_a_d is has current date.
This is what I am trying and I have to use that query in a view.
What I am trying is

```
(SELECT `pa`.value  FROM pa  WHERE pd
  =(SELECT MAX(`pa`.`pd`)) AND DATE(p_a_d) =
  DATE(CURRENT_DATE))  AS y
```

Comment: sql fiddle i have made is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f263/8

Comment: "the current date and max id" thes is no id in schema

Comment: @user3454116: For `max(pd)`, date of `p_a_d` is not current, in your data. and where conditions did not match and hence empty set.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if it helps with second part of your request

```
SELECT `pa`.value,`pa`.`pd`   FROM pa  
 WHERE 
 DATE(p_a_d) =  DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
order by `pa`.`pd` desc
limit 1
```

Comment: this query is wrking fine. BUt I want to use it in view so will it be working fine. This is what i am trying for example          select rd,
(SELECT `pa`.value   FROM pa  
 WHERE 
 DATE(p_a_d) =  DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
order by `pa`.`pd` desc) as y from pa

Comment: :see the sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f263/35. what I want is only fourth row to hold data for z (3596 2 2 4) remaining should contain null values. I hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
 SELECT `pa`.value  
 FROM pa  
 WHERE pd in (SELECT MAX(`pd`) from pa) 
 AND DATE(p_a_d) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24df00/1)

```
SELECT `pa`.value,ad,`l_l_d`  FROM pa  
WHERE pd
in (SELECT MAX(`pd`) from pa) 
AND DATE(p_a_d) =
DATE(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: your query is not returing any records. can you please check that.

Comment: because of the date , today we are 25 , i dont know what date you have today.

Comment: (1,3596,2,'2014-05-25 00:00:00',6.1,'2014-05-11 11:47:00'),
(2,3596,2,'2014-05-25 00:00:00',7.4,'2014-05-11 11:47:05') this data is present in the sqlfiddle

Comment: this data will not return something, because no date is today with max pd

Comment: this will give you result , as date today and have max pd http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce6f82/1

Comment: its giving me the result but i want to use this in a view ,so for example can you please see this  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce6f82/5. what I want is only fourth row to hold data for y (4 3596 4) remaining should contain null values for y. I hope its clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54376/discussion-between-user3454116-and-echo-me).